# (css) div inside div, centered and at the bottom

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to insert a div tag inside a div tag, where the child
is centered and positioned at the bottom. (I've tried several solutions from Stack Overflow with no success). With the following css and html examples, I'm having a problem

```
    body{
    margin:0;
    font-family:Georgia,Times,serif !important;
    font-size:12pt;
    background:white;
}

    #header{
        height: 60px;
        width: 100%;
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
    #navWrap{
        background:white;
        bottom: 0;
        font-size: 12pt;
        height: 40px;
        border: 1px solid black;
        margin: 0px auto;
        width: 960px;
    }


    #contentWrapper{
        width:960px;
        padding: 0;
        margin:15px auto 10px auto;
    }

    #content{
        padding: 20px 10px 10px 10px;
        height:100%;
        background:#fff;
        border: 1px solid black;
    }

    #footer {
        width:100%;
        height:260px;
        margin:0 auto;
        padding: 20px 10px 10px 10px;
        border: 1px solid black;
        bottom:0;
    }
    #copyright{
        width:100%;
        height:60px;
        bottom:0;
        margin: 0 auto;
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
<body>
    <div id="header">
        <div id="navWrap">
            This is navigation box.
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="contentWrapper">
        <div id="content">
            This is a container
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        This is a footer.
    </div>
    <div id="copyright">
        This is a copyright.
    </div>
</body>
```

I want the navigation (navWrap) inside the header position at the bottom. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Why would you comment that one answer worked, and yet accept a different one? If you mistakenly accepted one that you did not mean to accept, you can unaccept the mistaken answer and accept the correct one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to the header

```
position:relative
```

And then this to the navWrap

```
position:absolute;
left:50%;
margin-left:-480px; /* centering because your navWrap is 960px in width */
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fYxAQ/

Answer (score 0):

First, you'll need to position your `#header` relative, then position your `#navWrap` absolute.

Then, because you're absolutely positioning your `#navWrap` element, you're taking it out of context – its margin won't be able to be automatically positioned. To resolve this, shift the entire `<div>` halfway across the containing div by declaring `left: 50%;`, then bring it back by half of its own width by declaring `margin-left: -480px;`.

Try this CSS:

```
body{
    margin:0;
    font-family:Georgia,Times,serif !important;
    font-size:12pt;
    background:white;
}
#header{
    height: 60px;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    position: relative;
}
#navWrap{
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -480px;
    background:white;
    bottom: 0;
    font-size: 12pt;
    height: 40px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 960px;
}


#contentWrapper{
    width:960px;
    padding: 0;
    margin:15px auto 10px auto;
}

#content{
    padding: 20px 10px 10px 10px;
    height:100%;
    background:#fff;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#footer {
    width:100%;
    height:260px;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding: 20px 10px 10px 10px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    bottom:0;
}
#copyright{
    width:100%;
    height:60px;
    bottom:0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/kCwQP/.

Comment: Since it worked, would you please consider accepting this answer?